# Inkscape's export to PDF can't create PDF file

Tags: php, linux, macos, mamp, inkscape

I'm running the following line of PHP code to have Inkscape create a PDF from an SVG.

```php
$command = 'inkscape -z -f ' . $temp_destination . ' -A ' . $temp_pdf . ' -T';
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

When this is run though no PDF file is created.  So then I try and run the same command in Terminal under the user that PHP runs under (_www I'm using MAMP PRO)

```
sudo -u _www inkscape -z -f /path/to/tmp.svg -A /path/to/tmp.pdf -T
```

...and I get a lot of these errors below, even though the PDF is created now.

```
error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
```

How can I get this command be able to create the PDF file?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to check your php error log, or post additional information about errors received. Another question I would have is whether you are using absolute paths in the php script.

Comment: PHP isn't logging any errors when I do this.  The errors that I have seen I posted above about "Permission denied" and these are coming from executing that command.  I am using absolute paths.  Remember, when I run this under Terminal it works fine, but not when run through PHP's exec() function.